# Can a pure function call external function?

Tags: function, functional-programming, concept, pure-function

Can a pure function call an external method?

for example:

```
class Dog {
  function jump(name) {
    return "a dog named " + name + " jumped!"
  }

  function jumpTwice(names) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
       result.push(jump(names[i]));
    }
    return result.join("\n");
  }

}
```

can `jumpTwice()` be considered as a `pure function`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### When you can

A pure `f` function can call any other function/method `g0...gn`.
But `g0...gn` must be **pure** as well.

### When you cannot

As soon as you get a pure function `f` and you invoke a **non pure** function `g` from within `f`, then `f` is no longer pure.

Comment: But `jumpTwice` depends on what `jump` does. If the definition of `jump` changes, then the behaviour of `jumpTwice` changes. 

Doesn't it violate the "same input, same output" rule for pure functions?

Comment: Pure functions are not supposed to guarantee the same output if you change the codebase and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is pure. It doesn't mutate any global state nor gives different results for same input.

Answer (score 0):

In the specific case you give, yes. But what you have there is a method and methods require extra care.

Pure functions always give the same result for any given input, no matter what the current program state.. Methods can be viewed as functions which are passed their object as a hidden parameter. To be pure, the method must not access any implicit state (nor may they call any other methods/functions which are susceptible to implicit state). This means also not using any object fields which contain implicit state.  The comments discussion hopefully gives an example of how to judge that context.

It's not enough to shun mutable fields - the value in immutable fields field must be knowable/predictable . For example,  if an object contained an immutable private field which was given a random number on object creation, any method which used that value to compute it's output would be impure.

On the other hand, if your Dog class had an immutable name field which was set on object creation, then methods which used that field  can be considered pure (unless something else disqualifies them).

**EDIT**

It would have been helpful to say that "side effect" and "purity" is contextual (as discussed in the comments).  Which is what I didn't entirely clearly allude to by the use of the words "knowable" and "predictable".  The comments discussion illustrates the importance of knowing the context.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "knowable/predictable". All fields that are part of the object contribute to the input of the method. That the object creation is impure (involving randomness) does not make the method itself impure.

Comment: If the method ignores stateful properties of the object then it is predictable and pure. No matter what the mutable parts of the input, in that case, the output is predictable.

Comment: @Bergi to pick the most simple example, if a class method always returned the value **1** in any instance, it would be pure no matter how mutable the object's fields.

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that it does not need to ignore the mutable properties. It just must not alter them, it can access them without making anything impure.

Comment: If it uses mutable **values** to compute the output, it isn't pure.

Comment: No, it's pure as it does not mutate them. As properties of the object the method is called on, they are *explicit* input (and constant during the execution), not implicit mutable state.

Comment: I guess this breaks down to our definition of equality. Is an object in its old state equal to the same object with mutated properties? I say no, and then such a mutable object can be the input of a pure method.

Comment: By your argument, creating that object with the hidden random field and then calling a method which returns its value is a pure operation.  Which absolutely is not true.  Purity depends on context not least because "side effect" is only definable given a clear context) but that's precisely why I emphasised care with class methods.

Comment: No, creating the object with a hidden random field is not pure, only calling the method that returns the hidden field on the object is. And together, they are obviously impure.

Comment: Yes, if you're precise about the context then I concede your point.

Comment: As a good example of a functional OO I tend to point at the String class in Java. All the methods are pure and an instance never changes its state.